# Remove element from array inside React's return method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

There is a React component that receives via props some values:

```
class MyClass {
    render() {
        const {
            values,
            shouldRemove,
        } = this.props;
    }

    return (...);
}
```

if `shouldRemove` exists the last value from `values` must be removed.

I cannot remove it before return statement starts because I need that last value for the first part of the return.

So I've tried to set that `value` to empty if  `shouldRemove` exists from `values` array but didn't work.

```
return (
    <Table.Body>
        {values.map((value, valueIndex) => (
            //here I need that value too
        )}
        //from here I don't need it anymore
        {shouldRemove ? value = [] : value} // I added this line to set the element to empty. didn't work
        {value.map((item, itemIndex) => {
            //do something
        })
        }
    </Table.Body>
);
```

Any ideas about how to remove that element `values` array after the first step is run?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in `render()`.

```
render() {
    const {
      values,
      shouldRemove,
    } = this.props;

    const valuesAfterRemoval = shouldRemove ?
      values.slice(0, values.length-1) :
      values;

    return (
        <Table.Body>
            {values.map((value, valueIndex) => (
                // here I need that value too
            )}

            {valuesAfterRemoval.map((item, itemIndex) => {
                // do something
            })
        </Table.Body>
    );
}
```